# method which return a boolean but the the class file code return a void

Tags: java, android, lambda, bytecode, void

A method which return boolean value, when id decompile the class file, i find the method call another method which return a void value at the return position.

```java
Toolbar mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
     ensorsDataAutoTrackHelper.trackMenuItem(item);//the method is static and is void
     return false;
});
```

You can see that i call a method and return false.
`trackMenuItem` is defined as follow

```
public static void trackMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem)
```

I build the app's apk file, and decompile it. Because the lambda method will generate a tmp class. The result code is

```
public final /* synthetic */ class -$$Lambda$NavigationViewActivity$A_xAUBU6FC7Uc53_iFueQ6S_r1c implements OnMenuItemClickListener {
    public static final /* synthetic */ -$$Lambda$NavigationViewActivity$A_xAUBU6FC7Uc53_iFueQ6S_r1c INSTANCE = new -$$Lambda$NavigationViewActivity$A_xAUBU6FC7Uc53_iFueQ6S_r1c();

    private /* synthetic */ -$$Lambda$NavigationViewActivity$A_xAUBU6FC7Uc53_iFueQ6S_r1c() {
    }

    public final boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        return SensorsDataAutoTrackHelper.trackMenuItem(menuItem);
    }
}
```

You can see `onMenuItemClick` logic `return SensorsDataAutoTrackHelper.trackMenuItem(menuItem);`,

Why is it happened?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the decompiler might not able to handle lambdas correctly. Why are you decompiling your code in the first place?

Comment: I am studying the usage of lambda method. I am not sure if the problem of decompiler,  the decompiler is ' jadx'.

Comment: Can you post the actual jar file in question? That way we can try different decompilers.

Comment: "I am studying the usage of lambda method." - I still don't quite get why you'd have to decompile your code for that.

Comment: I have tried use 'dex-tools' to extract  the jar from APK file, and i use 'jd-gui' to decompile the jar file, but 'jd-gui' shows internal error. Here is my apk file: 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OJJqSHOvu7jAr_P8W4zrdrpB0N9N838-

Comment: @Thomas , I found it by accident.

Comment: Probably decompiler issue, check the bytecode instead, if there is usage of return with boolean and if called method have Z as return type.